# In CSS, what does "Make the divs such that they function as column." mean? and center the div

Tags: html, css

My qeustion is that How do I make two **divs tag that they function as column?**

Another question is how do I make the div element to use only 60% of the page width and **center the div within the page**? 
Is it like div{ margin:auto;width:60%;}?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp make reading a habit

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to set up a column layout is to simply have parent containers that have a `width` as a percentage. If you want two columns, you would have `width: 50%`, for example. If you are unsure of the percentage value you need, you can calculate this by dividing `100%` by the desired number of columns with [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
width: calc(100% / 3);  -- 3 columns (33.33%)
```

As for setting an element that's centralised with a `60%` `width`, all you need to do is set:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 60%;
```

Both of these can be seen in the following:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
}

.parent {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #626262;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  background: cyan;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent left-column">
    <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent right-column">
    <div class="child">Child 3</div>
    <div class="child">Child 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```